# Magento- Call to a member function setSaveParametersInSession() on a non-object in ~/container.php on line 59

Tags: php, mysql, xml, magento

I'm using Magento 1.5 and I'm getting a fatal error message when trying to access "Customers->Manage Customers" from Magento Backend.
error details :

> ```
> Call to a member function setSaveParametersInSession() on a non-object in
> ```
>
> /my_domain.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php
>   on line 59

and this is the peace of code inside Container.php where Magento gets stuck

> ```
> protected function _prepareLayout()
> {
>     $this->setChild( 'grid',
>         $this->getLayout()->createBlock( $this->_blockGroup.'/' . $this->_controller . '_grid',
>         $this->_controller . '.grid')->setSaveParametersInSession(true) );
>     return parent::_prepareLayout();
> }
> ```

any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not clear from the question, but ...

I suppose you got this error while you are creating a new module with a adminhtml controller.

If so ...

The error could be triggered by an erroneous `_blockGroup`  declaration in the blocks that extend `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container`

Hope it helps

Comment: @franceso ,can u help me?...i created a new module as yousaid .. then i got this error in front end.....What i do?

Comment: this is the error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816`

Comment: As I wrote above you probably wrongly set `_blockGroup` in the grid container

Answer (score 1):

I have just get the same issue when I go to the custom module in my site and see that I got the error because I miss file Grid.php in folder app/code/local/Magestore/Affiliateplus/Block/Adminhtml/Banner/Grid.php. When I upload this file again, the issue has been solved. 
Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Check your folder structure one more time to make sure that all the files are located at correct path.

In my case for this issue the file was placed at wrong location. I placed the Grid.php in controller/Adminhtml folder rather that Block/Adminhtml//Grid.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is the detail, in your case problem is initialization of block OR location of Grid.php. Follow this link it will help : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10848/setsaveparametersinsession-on-a-non-object